# What's the difference between maven-metadata.xml and pom.xml?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Sorry for the very newbie question I'm new to Maven.

I'm trying to use Ansible's module for Maven to download files from JFrog's Artifactory. And it's keeps on saying that the maven-metadata.xml is missing. Which makes sense since we are using pom.xml's in our production setup.

When I look online and I see the typical contents of these files they seem to contain the same things in them with: groupId, artifactId, version.

When, Where & Why? Would I want to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

`pom.xml` is one of the artifacts that are being deployed to remote repo. It has special features, but it's still one of the artifacts - it has a version, groupId, artifactId and a type.

`maven-metadata.xml` contains information *about* artifacts: a list of snapshot and release versions, the latest version. When Maven deploys new version of the artifacts it first downloads existing `maven-metadata.xml` (if it exists), adds the new version there and then re-uploads it back to the repo.

`maven-metadata.xml` can be rebuilt by repository manager based on the existing artifacts. At least it's possible in Sonatype Nexus. So if this file is missing - you can try finding similar feature in Artifactory.

Normally though you or your tools shouldn't use `maven-metadata.xml`, I haven't seen good use-cases. Some people are trying to get the latest version out of this file, but it's not really a reliable source for it.

Answer (score 0):

`maven-metadata.xml` is an internal file inside of a Maven repository, used by Maven to get metadata. Maven projects always have a `pom.xml`.

If the metadata file is missing, you probably lost some files in the Artifactory, or the repository in Artifactory is not a Maven repository.